# Java Android Media Player (Notification)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

So I have the following code and it is working fine, however I want to show the media controls in the users Notification area so they can play and stop the music as they please while the app is in the background.

I am wondering how one does this?

Code:

```
package com.radiomedia.a1liferadio;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imagePlayPause;
    private TextView textCurrentTime, textTotalDuration;
    private SeekBar playerSeekBar;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imagePlayPause = findViewById(R.id.imagePlayPause);
        textCurrentTime = findViewById(R.id.textCurrentTime);
        textTotalDuration = findViewById(R.id.textTotalDuration);
        playerSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.playerSeekBar);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        playerSeekBar.setMax(100);

        imagePlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }else{
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    updateSeekBar();
                }
            }
        });

        prepareMediaPlayer();
    }

    private  void prepareMediaPlayer() {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream"); //url of media
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
        } catch (Exception exception){
            Toast.makeText(this,exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekBar();
            long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            textCurrentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
        }
    };

    private void updateSeekBar(){
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            playerSeekBar.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaPlayer.getDuration()) * 100));
            handler.postDelayed(updater, 1000);
        }
    };

    private String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliSeconds) {
        String timerString = "";
        String secondsString;

        int hours = (int)(milliSeconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int minutes = (int)(milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 *60);
        int seconds = (int)((milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 *60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);

        if(hours > 0)
        {
            timerString = hours + ":";
        }

        if(seconds < 10)
        {
            secondsString = "0" + seconds;
        }else{
            secondsString = "" + seconds;
        }

        timerString = timerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;
        return timerString;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really want to know that your current configuration works in background well, please enable the "Don't keep activities" in developer options and test again. It should not work without a service!

Comment: Can you post a link to all of the app code? Or otherwise give the mindSdkVersion? I need to know so that I know which API's are possible to use.

Comment: Sapan Diwakar has written a comprehensive blog post about this:  https://sapandiwakar.in/android-media-player-lock-screen/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should follow this [old google mediaplayer sample](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-MediaBrowserService) (Use this [commit](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-MediaBrowserService/commit/212f926f4cdf49a11875d5ea9d60ffaf1dd1dd08) if the master version crashes for you) if you want to keep using the MediaPlayer.

But If you don't mind using ExoPlayer, then you should instead follow this [new one](https://github.com/android/uamp), since ExoPlayer can already take care of part of the notification stuff.

But so in these sample projects you can see that:

1. It's not as simple as just a notification, it also ties into people pressing on a play button on their headset etc.
2. You really need a service for this, to bind to the notification, to handle the action.MEDIA_BUTTON intents.

Minimal code for adding such a notification with a [MediaSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat) and Service with the MediaPlayer (so not ExoPlayer) like you are using would look something like this:
Add the media compat libraries to your apps' build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0"
}
```

Then create a class for creating the Notification:

```
package com.radiomedia.a1liferadio;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle;
import androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver;


/**
 * Keeps track of a notification and updates it automatically for a given MediaSession. This is
 * required so that the music service don't get killed during playback.
 */
public class MediaNotificationManager {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 412;

    private static final String TAG = MediaNotificationManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.android.musicplayer.channel";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 501;

    private final MediaSessionService mService;

    private final NotificationCompat.Action mPlayAction;
    private final NotificationCompat.Action mPauseAction;
    private final NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    public MediaNotificationManager(MediaSessionService musicContext) {
        mService = musicContext;

        mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) mService.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mPlayAction =
                new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_play,
                        "play",
                        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                                mService,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY));
        mPauseAction =
                new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_pause,
                        "pause",
                        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                                mService,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE));
        // Cancel all notifications to handle the case where the Service was killed and
        // restarted by the system.
        mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
    }

    public NotificationManager getNotificationManager() {
        return mNotificationManager;
    }

    public Notification getNotification(MediaMetadataCompat metadata,
                                        @NonNull PlaybackStateCompat state,
                                        MediaSessionCompat.Token token) {
        boolean isPlaying = state.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING;
        MediaDescriptionCompat description = metadata.getDescription();
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                buildNotification(state, token, isPlaying, description);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder buildNotification(@NonNull PlaybackStateCompat state,
                                                         MediaSessionCompat.Token token,
                                                         boolean isPlaying,
                                                         MediaDescriptionCompat description) {

        // Create the (mandatory) notification channel when running on Android Oreo.
        if (isAndroidOOrHigher()) {
            createChannel();
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mService, CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setStyle(
                new MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(token)
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0)
                        // For backwards compatibility with Android L and earlier.
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .setCancelButtonIntent(
                                MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                                        mService,
                                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP)))
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mService, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play)
                // Pending intent that is fired when user clicks on notification.
                .setContentIntent(createContentIntent())
                // Title - Usually Song name.
                .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
                // When notification is deleted (when playback is paused and notification can be
                // deleted) fire MediaButtonPendingIntent with ACTION_PAUSE.
                .setDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                        mService, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE));


        builder.addAction(isPlaying ? mPauseAction : mPlayAction);

        return builder;
    }

    // Does nothing on versions of Android earlier than O.
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannel() {
        if (mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID) == null) {
            // The user-visible name of the channel.
            CharSequence name = "MediaSession";
            // The user-visible description of the channel.
            String description = "MediaSession and MediaPlayer";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            // Configure the notification channel.
            mChannel.setDescription(description);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
            // channel, if the device supports this feature.
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(
                    new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            Log.d(TAG, "createChannel: New channel created");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "createChannel: Existing channel reused");
        }
    }

    private boolean isAndroidOOrHigher() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O;
    }

    private PendingIntent createContentIntent() {
        Intent openUI = new Intent(mService, MainActivity.class);
        openUI.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mService, REQUEST_CODE, openUI, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    }

}
```

Then Create a Service class that handles playback and the notification button presses:

```
package com.radiomedia.a1liferadio;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class MediaSessionService extends Service {
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public static final String TAG = "MediaSessionService";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 888;
    private MediaNotificationManager mMediaNotificationManager;
    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaNotificationManager = new MediaNotificationManager(this);
        mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "SOME_TAG");
        mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onPlay() {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        });
        Notification notification =
                mMediaNotificationManager.getNotification(
                        getMetadata(), getState(), mediaSession.getSessionToken());

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    public MediaMetadataCompat getMetadata() {
        MediaMetadataCompat.Builder builder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();

        builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "artist");
        builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "title");
        builder.putLong(
                MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, mediaPlayer.getDuration()
        );
        return builder.build();
    }

    private PlaybackStateCompat getState() {
        long actions = mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ? PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE : PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY;
        int state = mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ? PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING : PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED;

        final PlaybackStateCompat.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
        stateBuilder.setActions(actions);
        stateBuilder.setState(state,
                mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(),
                1.0f,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        return stateBuilder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if ("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) intent.getExtras().get("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT");
            if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Update your manifest for declaring the service and sending the action.MEDIA_BUTTON intent to it.

```
<service
    android:name=".MediaSessionService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This [MediaButtonReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver) above is needed for pre-OREO devices, it will forward the event to the service on those platforms.

Then start the service from your main activity.

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(
                            MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                            new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), MediaSessionService.class));
```

Things still to do here are making your main activity send actions to your service or the player in the service somehow, updating the notification and service state on a change, but you should be able to get something working with this code and figure out the rest from the google sample code.

Comment: this is not working for me it is showing app is working in background as a notification

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios :

First

1. if you want to play song in background you should have to start a forground service. forground service is with notification .(pass the seekbar position, play pause state, playlist or video url to service).
2. After you creating custome notification with media controls whatever you want
3. you have to add a media player to service also pass your parameters like position , play pause state to service player that it play from your previous state of activity player.
4. on click of notification you have to do same parameters pass to activity .

Second

Start forground service with attaching a player and bind the activity to it, and handle all controls from notification and activity at the same time.

- you can pass player controls to notfication in sense of froground service to start and play song in background .
- you can use preference or tinydb for best performance in getting parameters to pass in first case.

Comment: The music is playing in the background when the app is closed, but not showing in the Notification section. That is the part I don't know how to do. That's why I am asking. Do you have a sample code of how to make it work?

Comment: have you start a service to play song in background???

Comment: I believe so... At least the script above does work in background

Comment: have you checked it after kill the app is it running then ???

Comment: as i see in your code you have not started any of service you have to start the forground service to play song in background and controlling the player also .

Comment: if you want some of sample go to this  https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-MediaPlayer-play-in-background